# Python - Bokeh Interactive Legend - Attribute Error

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to make an interactive legend.

Even when I run the code in this link https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html

I get the error:

AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'legend_label' to Line, possible attributes are js_event_callbacks, js_property_callbacks, line_alpha, line_cap, line_color, line_dash, line_dash_offset, line_join, line_width, name, subscribed_events, tags, x or y

Any ideas why? I have the latest version of Bokeh, as far I know.

Comment: What Bokeh version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.3.4 (my bad). But when I run conda update bokeh in the anaconda prompt, it doesn't upgrade...

Answer (score 4):

Use `legend` instead of `legend_field` or `legend_label`.

Comment: This fixed my issue by changing 'legend_label' to 'legend'

Answer (score 2):

`legend_label` was added in version 1.4. You will have to update to that or later, or else refer to the docs specific to your version:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/1.3.4/docs/user_guide/interaction/legends.html

Comment: Thanks bigredot. I am still having some trouble with this.

Comment: I do conda install bokeh, then, conda list and it still shows by bokeh version as 1.3.4. How do I get version 1.4?

Comment: That's a separate (conda) question, I don't have an answer for. I only know that 1.4.0 and 2.0.0 both show up for me in a `conda search`. All I can suggest is to double check that you are actually installing in to the same conda env that you are running things from.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when installing bokeh through the shell first and through the conda later. This got me with two versions and the old one was preferred. 
I think what solved it for me: uninstalling previous versions, installing only conda (I have done it in Jupyter Notebook) and restarting the computer afterwards. Hope it helps.